# Missing .classpath file in Eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

I have recently returned to a project after not using it for a couple of weeks.  The project was not created in Eclipse it was imported, and there is no '.classpath' file in the project workspace.

I am sure that previously I successfully added new .jar files by simply right clicking them and going to 'Add to build path', but thanks to an unrelated error I had to re-add the files to the build path, and now whenever I try to add a new .jar file I get the following error:

```
Error while adding a library

Reason:
Could not write file C:\Users\Charles\workspace\hive\.classpath
```

Or, if I try to add a file using Configure build path, I get the following error:

```
'Setting build path' has encountered a problem.

Could not write file:
C:\Users\Charles\workspace\hive\.classpath
```

I have earlier versions of this project prior to adding .jar files, and there is no .classpath file for any of them either, so I haven't accidentally deleted it at any point.

If anyone can help me out at all, I'd be ever so grateful (I desperately need to add these .jar files so I can do some actual work).

The thing that annoys me the most is I'm sure it worked before, but I have tried to do the same in earlier versions of the project and I am always getting the same error now.

Comment: It looks like underlying os permission issue. What operation system are you using? Are .classpath hidden? If you are using mac, I suggest you use terminal and find out permission within your project folder. If you are using windows, then  check if hidden files visible option is set to true and use some utility like unlocker to see locking programs on the folder.

Comment: Have you checked if the file is read-only?

Comment: It was hidden.  Thanks very much.  I do feel like a bit of an idiot, but I'm curious to know why it worked previously, and then suddenly decided not to work (the file was DEFINITELY always set to hidden)?  Can anyone shed any light on this?  Thanks very much for your quick answers guys, very helpful.

Comment: yes, that file is normally hidden and managed by the IDE. So I guess thats why it is hidden. You dont need to edit manually.

Comment: I had to set it to visible before adding .jar files to my build path would work again, so something must have definitely happened.  Also, I checked on a couple of my other eclipse projects and the .classpath file was visible in all of them.

Comment: Just curious, visibility has nothing to do with the fact that the file is editable or not ( according to me ;) ). My guess is same .classpath is owned by an different eclipse project. Windows is cryptic, when it comes to permission locking. I used to use a utility called unlocker. It tells me all the process that holds a lock on a folder. ( I do not know why it has only 3 stars in cnet download now.)

Answer (score 48):

I had the same problem. I had just setup a new PC, I transferred my projects to the new PC, clicked on the workspace directory, and changed the permission so that I (the 'me' on my new PC) owned all the files in all all sub-directories. However, even after doing this, eclipse couldn't write to the .classpath files. I verified that I could write to them using notepad, and that worked fine. I also verified that the O/S knew I was really the owner, but it didn't help. I also tried running as admin, but that didn't help either.

Then I found this link: http://blog.ryanrampersad.com/2010/03/03/setting-build-path-has-encountered-a-problem-in-eclipse/, which indicates that when you copy files to a windows7 machine, windows may set the 'hidden' attribute on the file, and when this happens, eclipse can't work with it. I did a find files from the workspace directory, looking for '.project' (and subsequently '.classpath'), and selected all the files, right-clicked, and un-checked the 'hidden' attribute. This fixed my problem.

Comment: Is this just happen because of ".classpath" file name is not in windows standard file name rules?

Comment: Worked for me. Make sure to select all the files in the project folder and uncheck the hidden flag.

Answer (score 4):

The .classpath file in eclipse is a configuration file (in XML) which stores the project classpath properties.  If it can't be written, perhaps it's an access problem.  Right-click the file in windows explorer and check under the security tab to see if you have write permissions.  You may have to run Eclipse as administrator.

Comment: Although unlikely, but some process can also be locking it.

Comment: But `.classpath` file stores build path's properties... right?

Answer (score 2):

Go to your Project in WorkSpace.
And then change your files' attribute from hidden.

Also, then close-open your project and then clean it.

This should work.

Answer (score 2):

Right click Project >> Source >> Format - worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Go to the project folder and remove hidden property for the ".classpath" file. Hope this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The below solution worked for me.

Go to your project folder --> Right click folder --> Properties --> In general tab, Uncheck the attribute(last field), Read-only (Only applies to this folder) option.

Then try adding jars in eclipse.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

As doc_180 mentioned, the .Classpath would be hidden. Right click > Properties and Unhide the file, you should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue after trying to create my view on a new PC. The cause of the issue for me was that `.classpath` file was marked as read-only, for whatever reason. To resolve this I did the following:

Go to workspace directory --> Java Source folder --> Project Directory --> right click on `.classpath` and select Properties from the list --> uncheck 'Read-only' and/or 'Hidden' attribute checkbox(es) --> Click 'Apply' button.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem after changing my project to Gradle. When I right-clicked on javaw.exe->Properties in the 'debug' view, I saw the classpath was (mostly) missing, for instance the 'bin' directory containing the classes wasn't there.

Solution for me was just to delete the 'run debug configuration' and create a new one. After that the classpath was included and I could run it from Eclipse again.

Hope this helps someone out there.

Answer (score 0):

An intern here just had this problem. He put the project on the user Document folder. I moved his project to the Eclipse workspace folder, removed the project from Eclipse and imported it again. Then the .classpath file was generated.