# Unable to update maven configuration for the following project in spring tool suite

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-tool-suite

I'm getting this error for my project that is working well in my other PC. I have imported Maven project and tried to update maven dependencies and it says....

Unable to update maven configuration for the following project and Updating Maven has encountered a problem could not find .classpath

I'm using STS 3.0.0. JRE 1.7 ..

Comment: Does the file .classpath exist in the project root directory (anyway I've seen that if I delete a .classpath file inside one of my project the maven update recreate it) ? Are the folder/s and file/s permissions ok ? –

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8453370/233347

Answer (score 3):

May be you have a sourceDirectoy tag in your pom and where you specified 'src'
just remove it and it will do the job

Answer (score 1):

`Remove Maven Nature` of your `project`. And `Add Maven Nature` again.

Comment: Thanks for the response buddy But I tried that already and it didn't work for me

Comment: Is your `pom.xml` is in right place. Can you post your `project structure`?

Answer (score 1):

**Unable to update Maven configuration**
Could not calculate build plan:Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.7 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.7

I was getting this error while performing Maven Force Update Snapshots however same project I was able to force update in different workspace on the same machine.

Issue was Workspace not pointing to correct maven installation and settings.xml.

GO to Window > Preference > Maven > Installation
                   Point to to correct maven installation
Window > Preference > Maven > User Settings
  Both global and user settings points to correct settings.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same problem when I imported a maven project to my workspace.
I solved that issue by just closing the project and re-open it, then run the update maven configuration on it.